# C# Selenium I cannot scrape through tables

Tags: c#, selenium

This is the HTML

```
<table class="roomstable" id="maxotel_rooms" cellspacing="0" border="2">

<thead>
  <tr id="maxotel_table_header">
    <th class="figure">Max</th>
      <th>Room type</th>
        <th class="figure" style="white-space:normal"></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr class="odd first">
    <td class="occ_no_dates";">
      <span class="jq_tooltip with_kids" id="b_tt_holder_8" data-title="Max adults: 2<br/>Max children: 1 (up to 4 years of age)">
        <i class="b-sprite occupancy_max2 jq_tooltip" title="Standard occupancy: 2"></i>
          <span class="plus_kids">+</span>
        <i class="b-sprite occupancy_kid1"></i>
      </span>
    </td>
    <td class="ftd">
      Suite with Balcony
    </td>
```

This is my code

```
        var roomTypes = driver.FindElement(By.Id("maxotel_rooms")).FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
        foreach (var roomType in roomTypes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(roomType.FindElement(By.ClassName("ftd")).Text);
            Console.WriteLine(roomType.FindElement(By.ClassName("b-sprite")).GetAttribute("title"));
        }
```

I want to get multiple elements from this table . Every element with class name "ftd" and every element with class name "b-sprite" but the program cant find them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it by TagName("tbody") and then by TagName("tr")

```
var table = driver.FindElement(By.Id("maxotel_rooms")).FindElement(By.TagName("tbody"));
            var roomTypes = table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
            foreach (var roomType in roomTypes)
            {
                var persons = roomType.FindElement(By.ClassName("b-sprite"));
                //The type of the room
                var type = roomType.FindElement(By.ClassName("ftd")).Text;

                //The number of the adults
                var adults = persons.GetAttribute("title");
                var adultsNumber =  adults[adults.Length - 1];
            }
```